Excel error when merging data using Openpyxl
I wrote this script:

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
Days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday","Monday1", "Tuesday1", "Wednesday1", "Thursday1", "Friday1", "Sunday1"]
occupied_days = ["Saturday"]
ranges = [
    [(600, 730), (800, 1200), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(1500, 2200)],
    [(600, 730), (800, 1200), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(600, 730), (1300, 1900), (2130, 2300)],
    [(1500, 2200)]
]
def export_schedule_to_excel(schedule):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    earlies = []
    lates = []

    for x in schedule.values():
        if len(x) > 0:
            earlies.append(min(x, key=lambda s: s[2][0]))
            lates.append(max(x, key=lambda s: s[2][1]))
    earliest = min(earlies, key=lambda s: s[2][0])[2][0]
    latest = max(lates, key=lambda s: s[2][1])[2][1]
    time_5 = [x for x in range(earliest, latest + 5, 5)]  # Ensure the range includes the latest time
    for i, t in enumerate(time_5, start=2):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=1, value=t)

    for i, d in enumerate(Days):
        ws.cell(row=1, column=i+2, value=d)
    r, c = 2, 2
    for course, assignments in schedule.items():
        for assignment in assignments:
            name, day, (start, end) = assignment
            r1 = time_5.index(start) + r
            r2 = time_5.index(end) + r
            day_col = Days.index(day) + c
            print(r2,r1,day_col)

            # Assign value to the top-left cell before merging
            ws.merge_cells(start_row=r1, start_column=day_col, end_row=r2, end_column=day_col)
            cell = ws.cell(row=r1, column=day_col, value=f"{course}:{name}")
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
    wb.save("schedule.xlsx")

courses_hom = {
    "Algebra 2": {"Chapter 1 Review in Textbook": 200, "Read: Linear Equations in One Variable": 200,
                  "Read: An Introduction to Problem Solving": 200, "Read: Formulas and Problem Solving": 200},
    "Biology": {"Taxonomy & Scientific Method Recorded Lesson Check": 125, "Water Investigation Post Lab": 200},
    "English 3": {"Eng 3 Orientation Worksheet": 100, "Read: Reading Deeper, Writing Stronger (RDWS)": 150,
                  "Rhetorical Appeals Worksheet": 150, "Finding the Message Chart": 400,
                  'Read: Staples "Just Walk on By"': 400, '"Just Walk on By" Quiz': 400,
                  'Read: Mairs, "On Being a Cripple"': 400, '"On Being a Cripple" Quiz': 400},
    "History": {'Read: WH-What is History?': 300, 'Read: MWR-Introduction': 300, 'What is History?-Questions': 300,
                'MWR Intro-Questions': 300, 'Read: Skill Building: CEA Writing Strategy': 300,
                'Read: Skill Building: Chicago/Turabian Style for Research Papers': 300},
    "Java": {"Read: Inputs and Outputs Reading": 130, "Print a Poem with Java": 30}
}
def distribute_homework(Days, occupied_days, ranges, courses_hom):
    schedule = {}
    day_index = 0
    used_time_slots = {day: [] for day in Days}

    for course, assignments in courses_hom.items():
        schedule[course] = []
        for assignment, duration in assignments.items():
            while duration > 0:
                if Days[day_index] not in occupied_days:
                    for time_range in ranges[day_index]:
                        start, end = time_range
                        available_time = end - start
                        if available_time >= duration and (start, end) not in used_time_slots[Days[day_index]]:
                            schedule[course].append((assignment, Days[day_index], (start, start + duration)))
                            used_time_slots[Days[day_index]].append((start, start + duration))
                            duration = 0
                            break
                        elif available_time < duration and (start, end) not in used_time_slots[Days[day_index]]:
                            schedule[course].append((assignment, Days[day_index], (start, end)))
                            used_time_slots[Days[day_index]].append((start, end))
                            duration -= available_time
                day_index = (day_index + 1) % len(Days)
    return schedule
totals = 0
for x in ranges:
    for m in x:
        totals+=m[1]-m[0]

print(totals)
totals_hw = 0
for x in courses_hom:
    for m in courses_hom[x].values():
        totals_hw+=m
print(totals_hw)
if totals_hw>totals:
    print("impossible!")
schedule = distribute_homework(Days, occupied_days, ranges, courses_hom)
print(schedule)
export_schedule_to_excel(schedule)

and it worked without reporting an error. 
However when I tried to open the workbook using Excel it gave me a warning asking to recover the sheet because there seems to be some wrong format.
I tried debugging, and found that if I write
ws.merge_cells(start_row=r1, start_column=day_col, end_row=r1+20, end_column=day_col) 

or
r1+a number the Excel workbook opens fine.
If the number exceeds an amount, there will be an error since there will be overlap between the times.
But the original code works fine without giving a bug.

This code is almost impossible to debug. Did you use some kind of generator? If you want to create a schedule, you might want to look at using a linear solver.

The reason for your issue is you have clashes of times that cause overlapping merges.
For example 'Algebra 2' has these times set as the first Topic
('Chapter 1 Review in Textbook', 'Monday', (800, 870)),
('Read: Linear Equations in One Variable', 'Tuesday', (1300, 1370)), 

then later when you get to the 'English 3' Topic you have these times which overlap the existing 'Algebra 2' times, thus resulting in merged ranges overlap.
('Read: Mairs, "On Being a Cripple"', 'Monday', (800, 1200)), 
('"On Being a Cripple" Quiz', 'Tuesday', (1300, 1700))], 

There may be other overlaps but once the first one is written in English 3 the workbook (well Sheet actually) is corrupted.
However 
Ultimately it looks like your distribute_homework function needs to be overhauled.
Given it returns a time schedule like
('Chapter 1 Review in Textbook', 'Monday', (800, 870)),

Start time 800 and end time of 870
Also returns two time schedules for the one Assignment which may be by design if the 1st time period selected does not cover the required time duration.
{
'Algebra 2': [
('Chapter 1 Review in Textbook', 'Monday', (600, 730)), 
('Chapter 1 Review in Textbook', 'Monday', (800, 870)), 
('Read: Linear Equations in One Variable', 'Tuesday', (600, 730)), 
('Read: Linear Equations in One Variable', 'Tuesday', (1300, 1370)), 
...

I dont know what your requirements for setting the schedules is supposed to be but it appears incorrect.
Using the first assignment for 'Algebra 2'
"Chapter 1 Review in Textbook": 200
I presume that you want to assign a time of 200 (2hrs or is it 200 minutes?), it assigns the first range (600, 730) then assigns the next time range as (800, 870) the 70 being the difference of 200(duration) - 130(730-600).
Given you're scheduling time and the time blocks are hour or 1/2 hour you'd be better off to set your range to 30 or 15 min intervals and use time calculations to accurately add/subtract time from the ranges rather than have these nonsense times like 800 - 870.

More specifically, Excel will not allow cells to be merged into different ranges. If you look at the merged cells, you see that several ranges overlap: ws.merged_cells.sorted(). You have ranges like H2:H22 and H2:H28.

@CharlieClark, THX! I'm fixing the algorithm.
